Shared Library does not run inside a Pod/Container
I have a question regarding the execution of shared Library methods within a K8s POD/container.
I have a simple shared library example, which does, among other things, create a folder, yes, it does other things and in fact that doesn't matter now. The fact is that it works, I have been testing Docker agents in Jenkins. https://github.com/faustobranco/devops-db/tree/master/infrastructure/pipelines/lib-utilities
But when I create it in K8, using multi-containers, as in the example pipeline below, the method does not run within the indicated container. The sh, sever call is just for testing and indicating that I am in the correct container.
@Library('devopsdb-global-lib') _

import devopsdb.utilities.Utilities
def obj_Utilities = new Utilities(this)                        

pipeline {
    agent {
//        kubernetes {
//            yamlFile 'file-pod/resources/pods/file-pod.yaml'
//            retries 2
//        }
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          labels:
            some-label: "pod-template-${env.BUILD_ID}"
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: container-1
            image: registry.devops-db.internal:5000/img-jenkins-devopsdb:2.0
            env:
            - name: CONTAINER_NAME
              value: "container-1"
            volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-volume
              mountPath: /mnt
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          - name: container-2
            image: ubuntu:22.04
            env:
            - name: CONTAINER_NAME
              value: "container-2"
            volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-volume
              mountPath: /mnt
            command:
            - cat
            tty: true
          volumes:
          - name: shared-volume
            emptyDir: {}            
        """
        }
    }
    options { timestamps ()
        skipDefaultCheckout(true)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Environment') {
            steps {
                container('container-1') {
                    script {
                        sh 'echo $CONTAINER_NAME > /mnt/shared_volume.txt'
                        def str_folder = "/mnt/pipelines/resources"
                        def str_folderCheckout = "/pip"
                        obj_Utilities.CreateFolders(str_folder)
                        sh 'sleep 10m'
                        obj_Utilities.SparseCheckout('git@gitlab.devops-db.internal:infrastructure/pipelines/resources.git',
                                'master',
                                str_folderCheckout,
                                'usr-service-jenkins',
                                str_folder)
                        sh 'sleep 1s'
                        sh "PIP_CONFIG_FILE=${str_folder}${str_folderCheckout}/pip-devops.conf pip install devopsdb"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}

The result of the check inside the Container: It is clear that the folder is not created, but the file is.
Again, the issue is not creating the folder itself, that's what sh solves, the problem is that shared doesn't run inside the container, this prevents me, for example, from using the lib for sparse checkout.
kubectl get pods --namespace jenkins-devopsdb
NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS     AGE
infrastructure-pipelines-tests-test-file-pod-28-hvhmc-btx-zp14d   3/3     Running   0            61s


kubectl get pods infrastructure-pipelines-tests-test-file-pod-28-hvhmc-btx-zp14d --namespace jenkins-devopsdb -o="custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,INIT-CONTAINERS:.spec.initContainers[*].name,CONTAINERS:.spec.containers[*].name"
NAME                                                          INIT-CONTAINERS   CONTAINERS
infrastructure-pipelines-tests-test-file-pod-28-hvhmc-btx-zp14d   <none>            container-1,container-2,jnlp



kubectl exec -i -t infrastructure-pipelines-tests-test-file-pod-28-hvhmc-btx-zp14d --container container-1 --namespace jenkins-devopsdb -- /bin/bash
root@infrastructure-pipelines-tests-test-file-pod-28-hvhmc-btx-zp14d:/pipeline# ls -lah /mnt/
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K Jun 26 10:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jun 26 10:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   12 Jun 26 10:24 shared_volume.txt

If I let the pipeline continue:
11:39:36  ERROR: Checkout failed
11:39:36  Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 172.21.5.156/172.21.5.156:26427
11:39:36  at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
11:39:36  at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
11:39:36  at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1003)
11:39:36  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1226)
11:39:36  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1215)
11:39:36  at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1406)
11:39:36  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:845)
11:39:36  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1294)
11:39:36  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
11:39:36  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
11:39:36  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
11:39:36  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
11:39:36  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
11:39:36  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
11:39:36  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
11:39:36  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
11:39:36  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
11:39:36  java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /mnt/pipelines


if the same's been used in both docker and k8s, then it's probably the configuration of k8s pod to run as temp jenkins agent, check cloud setup for k8s
assuming your image is derived from official jenkins agent image, check container command to be something like java -jar /path/agent.jar and args like 'jnlpUrl http://servicename.namespace:port/computer/${computer.name}/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret ${computer.jnlpmac} -workDir "/home/jenkins'
this docs is for Kubernetes plugin and i think it might be helpful for you  https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/

I followed the Plugin documentation, for containers, I have normal images, derived from Ubuntu, for example. One of them (container-1) is derived from jenkins:jenkins. My Jenkins master is in a VM and K8 is a separate service, it has been working well, but I don't understand where (whether container, pod, etc.) the shared library method is being run.

With some additional debugging, it seems to me that, regardless of the container I indicate in the pipeline step, everything from the Shared Library runs in the jnlp container.
Is this really the expected behavior or am I instantiating it wrong?

as per my knowledge you need to install the jenkins agent in order to turn the pod that  jenkins create temporarily to run the pipeline onto jenkins agent node , you can use the official jenkins-agent image with the linux distro you desire, add your custom packages, tools in it, then upload that image and use it.

then go to manage jenkins > cloud , and configure the k8s cluster, container & pod configs, commands, and much more

The fact is that the Shared Library really only runs in the jnlp container, I made the explicit declaration of the jnlp container with the shared volume and everything was fine. This is in this specific case where I have to have the SL results in a separate volume, otherwise only the workspace, which is common across all, resolves the issue.

AccessDeniedException: /mnt/pipelines seems to point to permissions issue.
